# При подключении базы данных ошибка: @dp.message_handler(commands=['start']) AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Хочу подключить БД к боту для его локализации, при подключении выскакивает ошибка:

```
 @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Пробовал пересоздавать проект, локальное окружение, переустанавливать aiogram,в общем, все виды танцев с бубном

```
    import logging
    from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
    from config import TOKEN
    from db import Database
    import markups as kb
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    bot = Bot(TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    dp = Database('database.db')
    
    @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def start(message: types.Message):
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите язык', reply_markup=kb.langMenu)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет')
    
    @dp.message_handler()
    async def mess(message: types.Message):
        pass


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

В самом db класс Database, который организует выбор языка, в строчке с db.user_exists проверяется регистрация пользователя:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("select * from users where user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id, lang):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("insert into users (user_id, lang) values (?,?)", (user_id, lang,))

    def get_lang(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("select lang from users where user_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()[0]
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том что Вы создаете объекты:

```
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp = Database('database.db')
```

Можно сделать так :

```
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db_database = Database('database.db')
    
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    if not db_database.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
          await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите язык', reply_markup=kb.langMenu)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет')
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста.  Я бы еще Вам порекомендовал отказаться от `with` и писать класс для БД асинхронно.